# React Native - How to Style individual elements of a Text object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to style an element of a Text object with React Native?

I have the following Text object:

```
<Text style={styles.status}>Game Status: {gameStatus}</Text>
```

I'd like to add style around the gameStatus itself.

With HTML I'd simply add and style a span tag for example -

```
<Text style={styles.status}>Game Status: <span {styles.statusHighlight}>{gameStatus}</span></Text>
```

but nested span tags don't appear to be allowed within text objects in React N - how can I achieve the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React native supports nested Text components

So Change

```
  <Text style={styles.status}>Game Status: <span {styles.statusHighlight}>{gameStatus}</span></Text>
```

To

```
  <Text style={styles.status}>Game Status: <Text style={styles.statusHighlight}>{gameStatus}</Text></Text>
```

Comment: You are welcom